# How to create an alert expression on gauge metric

Tags: prometheus, grafana, alert, victoriametrics

I have job_status_gauge{jobName="someJob", haveError="false"} metric, and it has 2 conditions (one when job starts, and zero when job ends), there is different jobs, but i want for now just "someJob".

I want to create using vmalert something like sum_over_time(job_status_gauge{jobName="someJob", haveError="false"}[24h]) < 1
but it's not working, how can i fix that? (Maybe i need to convert timeseries into something else?)

So the alert would be, if there is no number 1 in metric for 24h then fire an alert.

Comment: And what is shown in Web console for this query? Preferably without <1 part.

Comment: Could you please specify what the alerting rule should do in detail?